# SearchBar is blocking until I press Cancel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I really tried very much but I can't figure it out.
I implemented a Search Bar in a TableView and when I search something the the methods are running in the Background but nothing happens in the User Interface until I click the Cancel Button. After I clicked this Button everything is running exactly like I wanted.

```
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    performSearchWithText(searchText: searchBar.text!)
}
    private func performSearchWithText(searchText: String) {
    self.photos = []

    FlickrBrain.fetchPhotosForSearchText(searchText: searchText, onCompletion: {
        (error: NSError?,flickrPhotoIds:[String]?)-> Void in

        if error == nil {
            self.photoIds = flickrPhotoIds!

                  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.title = searchText
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })


        }else {
            self.photoIds = []
            if (error!.code == FlickrBrain.Errors.invalidAccessErrorCode) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.showErrorAlert()
                })
            }
        }


    })
}
```

It would save me a lot of time if somebody can help me, I tried everything i can

Comment: How is `self.photoIds = flickrPhotoIds!` updating your UI?

Comment: sorry I added the missig snippet

Comment: when you search is the title getting changed `self.title = searchText`?

Comment: no nothing happens until i click the Cancel Button and everything loads instantly